# Java - Retrieve values from String, implementing either Scanner() or Pattern() & Matcher(), or other

Tags: java

I have a `String`:

```
    String message1 = "Request: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.me.test.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <ws:RequestTypeOne>
          <userId>user_name_one</userId>
       </ws:RequestTypeOne>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>";
```

1) I need to be able to able to extract the starting word - it can be either *Request* or *Repsonse*, so I can store in another `String`.

2) I need to be able to extract what is in between the  tag, and store this into another String too.

I have had a go with `Scanner()` with `useDelimiter()`, but I am not sure how to implement this. I have also tried pattern() and matcher() but I am not sure this is the best for this requirement.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: if you know for sure that your string will be in some known format then using a regex (using matcher) is the way to go. (provided you document it well for the next guy to maintain your code).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to scrape a log file. You'd be better off formatting the log as XML to start with.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String type =  message1.substring(0, message1.indexOf(':'));
    String userId = message1.substring(message1.indexOf("<userId>") + 8, message1.indexOf("</userId>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used regex and http://rubular.com for your requests.

1. `/^(Request|Response)/` extracts only this words
2. `/\W<(.*)>/` extracts all characters within the `< >`. Warning: In the result list, the `< >` won't be included.